# xmlHttpRequest/AJAX Calls are blocking all Servlet calls after refreshing 3 times

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, xmlhttprequest, tomcat8

I am trying to get data to UI by making ajax calls to Servlet. Following is the code that I am using to make these calls,

```
function callServlet(paramString, mapping){
    var url = contextPath + "/" + mapping;
    var strObj;
    $.ajax({

    url: url,
    data: paramString,
    type: 'POST',
    async : false,
    cache : false,
    beforeSend:function(){
      console.log("hello");
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data) {
      console.log('data', data);
      strObj = data;
     }
    },
    error:function(a,b,e)
    {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
 return strObj;
}
```

I have 5 of these calls done when my page loads which populate various parts of my UI. After I refresh the page 3 times, page gets stuck at one of these 5 servlet calls. But when I restart tomcat server, everything works as expected for 3 times and then gets stuck again.

Note:
I was able to make numerous calls to the above used Servlet from POSTMAN Client. It only gets stuck when I use Ajax or xmlHttpRequest to call the servlet.

Can anyone suggest what I can do with this issue?
Please ask if any other information is needed.

Comment: Can you show anything from the servlet side?

Comment: Servlet I am using sends an SQL query to database and converts the fetched data into JSON format and returns the data to the caller. This servlet is not blocked even after I do numerous call to it from browser/POSTAMN.